# ngCordova: Uncaught ReferenceError: Connection is not defined

Tags: javascript, networking, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Trying to figure out this error in my Ionic app for checking network connection.  Im using ngCordova's network tools found here :

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/

ngCordova claims that their `$cordovaNetwork.isOnline()` function works but I'm finding quite the opposite.  `$cordovaNetwork.getNetwork` seems to work fine but otherwise, I am getting this error when executing `console.log($cordovaNetwork.inOnline());` in the code.

[image: error]

I've seen answers to this issue elsewhere but none of them involve using this function.  They involve using a states array or 'online/offline' events.

Can someone explain why `isOnline() || isOffline()` doesn't seem to work?  How can I use this function accordingly without any circus tricks? I am debugging via Android. I am injecting properly and doing other things properly in the code.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe a lot of these cordova plugins aren't meant to be used in a browser and have to be tested on the emulator or device

Comment: I tried doing that as well, but it is a lot harder to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve this, I had 2 workarounds for this problem
1- In Cordova/service.

```
this.isOffline = function() {
    if (navigator.connection && typeof Connection !== 'undefined') {
        me.offline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline();
        return me.offline;
    }
    return me.offline;
 };
```

2- Include a new file connection.js in index.html(first js file) with below content

```
var Connection = {
UNKNOWN: "unknown",
ETHERNET: "ethernet",
WIFI: "wifi",
CELL_2G: "2g",
CELL_3G: "3g",
CELL_4G: "4g",
CELL:"cellular",
NONE: "none"
};
```

there may be one more reason for this problem i.e ngCordova is firing up before the device is ready.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log($cordovaNetwork.inOnline());
```

It must be isOnline.You have a typo here.It is wrong copy paste or you have this in the code?

Comment: I dont believe it is wrong as I tried logging both ways to the console.  Both gave the same Uncaught Reference Error

Comment: Since you can’t access Cordova plugins when running through a desktop browser you must use navigator.online for webview.

Comment: I'm debugging via Android though

Comment: Please see my other post to solve your problem for sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805050/navigator-online-on-ionic-app/38807315#38807315

Comment: Your other post looks legit, but it involves circus tricks for a simple command for isOnline() that ngCordova claims to provide

Comment: At this point, I think $cordovaNetwork is not the way to go.  theres probably a node package that could work a lot better